# Remove slugs from custom posts type

Tags: php, permalinks, slug

I am trying to remove custom posts name from permalink, this code works fine for one custom post but I am trying to remove the slug for 3 more custom posts. Can anyone help me rewrite it to handle many custom posts instead of one.

```
function vipx_remove_cpt_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( ! in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'internal_doors' ) ) || 'publish' != $post->post_status )
        return $post_link;

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'vipx_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 3 );

function vipx_parse_request_tricksy( $query ) {

    // Only noop the main query
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    // Only noop our very specific rewrite rule match
    if ( 2 != count( $query->query )
        || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) )
        return;

    // 'name' will be set if post permalinks are just post_name, otherwise the page rule will match
    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'internal_doors', 'page' ) );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'vipx_parse_request_tricksy' );
```

Comment: are you creating your custom post type with the function 'register_post_type'? if so there is a parameter called 'rewrite' which let's you customize the permalink stucture: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#rewrite

Comment: I am using plugin CPT UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( ! in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'internal_doors' ) ) || 'publish' != $post->post_status )
```

replace above with

```
 if ( ! in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'internal_doors','custom post type name1', 'custom post type name2' ) ) || 'publish' != $post->post_status )
```

and

```
if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'internal_doors', 'page' ) );
```

replace this with

```
if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'internal_doors','custom post type name1', 'custom post type name2', 'page' ) );
```

note: change custom post type name1, custom post type name2 with your original names

Comment: @wushu06 .. mark the answer as accepted